# Anyway that I can pass a table from one page to another pop-up page in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does anyone know whether i can pass a table from a page to another pop-up page when the button been clicked?

Example:
In page A, I have the following code :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alan</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Amy</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

when I clicked on the following javascript, new page will pop-up and it will passing the same table and information over:

```
window.open("pgTest.aspx");
```

Do anyone know whether it's possible happen in jquery, javasctip or ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function in the parent window using opener.functionName and in that you can access the table in the parent window.

For more details read [**`window.opener`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener)

***In your parent (opener) window***

```
<table id="table1">
    ....
</table>

function getTable() {
    var tableObj = document.getElementById("table1");
    return tableObj;
}
```

***In your child window***

```
opener.getTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new window, you can write whatever you want as its content, so you can do:

```
myNewWindow.document.write('<html><title></title>' + someElement.innerHTML + '</html>');
myNewWindow.document.close();
```