# Pass <table> id from one page to another page in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **3 types of tables** with id values.. I am redirecting the page from one to another page. While redirecting it will go to that exact page and the exact **table**.. I don't know how to do this in **jQuery**?

```
<table id="backgroundCheck" >
```

**Route Page:**

```
<a href="../../../../Main/MainPage/index"  target="_blank" >
                    <img src="../../Content/Images/1.jpg" width="64" height="64">
                    <span>Connect</span>
```

Here I am redirecting from one page to another page.. how to do here to go the exact table id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tblID=$("body").find("table").attr("id"); 
    <a href='YourPage#+'tblID+' >Other page</a>
```

Here , tblID is ID of table you are passing.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the situation correctly, you can use an anchor on the link to go to a part of the page. Example `<a href="/mypage#IdOnPage">Link</a>` will take the user to /mypage and scroll to the element with id="IdOnPage". No jQuery required.

Answer (score 1):

API you are looking for is `window.opener` :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener

> Window.opener => Returns a reference to the window that opened this current window.

See here the implementation: [Anyway that I can pass a table from one page to another pop-up page in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012975/anyway-that-i-can-pass-a-table-from-one-page-to-another-pop-up-page-in-jquery)

Hope this helps! `:)`

**Sample code**

```
<table id="backgroundCheck">
  <td>...stufff
</table>

function getTableInfo() {
    var tableObj = document.getElementById("backgroundCheck");
    return tableObj;
}
```

**Then on the new window**

Do this => `opener.getTableInfo`